# Sphero: openConnectionWithSpecificRobot or analog in official SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, sphero-api

I don't understand how I can start communication session with specific robot or with all connected (available) robots. I have "availableRobots"=2 and array with both robots. What next? In official SDK for iOS I don't see any method similar to "openConnectionWithSpecificRobot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the iOS SDK only supports communication with one robot. Prior to iOS 6 Apple only allowed communication with one device of any type.  This was supposedly fixed in an iOS 6 update, although we have not had the chance to test this yet.  If so we hope to release an update at some point in the future that will support communication with multiple robots on iOS.